# More than one one-to-one relationship on a entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

You see my model structure on Entity Framework 5.0 and User entity hold reference to Address and Address1 entities. In the other side, Address hold Users collection as reference but Entity framework couldn't know that Users dependendant on which Address reference So i got exception.

What are solutions exist for it ? I mean fluent and none-fluent solutions please.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Address Address1 { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you have a collection of `Address` instead?

Comment: No I dont need to hold collection instead of 2 reference.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to include the foreign keys in User class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int Address1Id { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Address Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Address)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AddressId);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Address1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.Address1Id);
```

More details here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Comment: Is there also none-fluent solution ?

Comment: @Freshblood mark your navigation properties [ForeignKey("foreignKeyName")]

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare but here you missing a thing. ForeignKey attrbitue only helpfull when you want to specify foreignKey properties but it has nothing to do with relationship in otherside of relation. I mean Reservations navigation on Address.

Comment: It's also important to add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` to `.HasFroeignKey(u => u.Address1Id)` or you will get SQL errors (this info is also in the linked article)

Comment: @MattR I prefered to keep ForeignKey Nullable  by specifiying HasOptional in fluent api.In this way cascade delete is false default

Comment: @MattR: agreed, I had that problem myself.